# Variable data type error as I add a decimal into one axis of vector 3 force

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity, I want one component of my vector 3 to increase as I collide with an in game object, but I get a data type error whenever I run the code.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;
    public Text countText;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private int count;
    private int speedcount;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        count = 0;
        speedcount = 1;
        SetCountText();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float HorizontalMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(-(HorizontalMove), 0.0f, -0.5f);
        rb.AddForce(movement * speed * speedcount);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
      if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Blue Cube"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            speedcount = speedcount + 0.1;
        }
```

Comment: `speedcount` is `int`, `speedcount = speedcount + 0.1;` won't work. Change it to `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`speedcount` is declared as an **integer**. But you try to add a floating-point value to it (a double to be exact: `0.1`).

You will have to choose one of the following solutions:

1. Declare `speedcount` as a **float** : `private float speedcount;` and do the following sum `speedcount = speedcount + 0.1f`
2. Change the increment when you do the sum computation: `speedcount = speedcount + 1`